# for/if PHP omitindo elemento

Tags: php, laravel, loop, if

estou com um grande problema. Tenho um sistema em PHP/LARAVEL que emite relatório em PDF. O sistema ela está omitindo um elemento na hora de colocá-lo em um array.

Acredito que seja na hora de montar o loop e fazer as comparações de if estou deixando passar algo.

Tenho uma lista de pessoas e tenho que listar 9 pessoas por página, a 10 pessoa que deveria estra na próxima página não aparece ele pula essa pessoa e o fato se repete de 10 em 10 elementos. A solução pode ser simples mas não estou conseguindo pensar.

OBS: O retorno dos elementos na base de dados trás todas as pessoas.

> $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor; Onde [$p] é a página e o [$j] o elemento na página

Espero que vocês possam me ajudar.

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$p = 0;
$dep = '';
$pdep = '';

$aux = count($servidores);

foreach ($servidores as $value => $servidor) {

    $servidor->ferias = $ferias[$value]->ferias;

    if($value == 0){
        $pdep = $servidor->cd_departamento;
        $dep = $servidor->cd_departamento;
        $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;
        $j++;
    }else{
        if($dep == $servidor->cd_departamento){
            if ($j < 9) {
                $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;
                $j++;
            } else {
                $p++;
                $j = 0;
                $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;
            }
        }else{
            $dep = $servidor->cd_departamento;
            $p++;
            $j = 0;
            $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `$servidores_separados_por_pagina = array_chunk($servidores, 9);`

Comment: Eu acabei não explicando, mas o sistema tem uma peculiaridade, caso a pessoa seja de um departamento diferente da pessoa anterior ele deverá começar uma nova página.

Comment: tem como mandar o conteudo da variavel servidores?

Comment: @douglaspjuizfora, e como sabe que a pessoa pertence a um departamento diferente?

Comment: Ele vem com todos os registros do objeto servidores. Na hora de colocar esse objeto dentro dos array é onde está o problema. Ele está comento os elementos 10,20,30,40 e assim por diante que no código seria os elementos (9,19,29,39 ...)

Comment: @Vitor Carnaval, eu guardo os elementos nas variáveis "$pdep = $servidor->cd_departamento;
                            $dep = $servidor->cd_departamento; e Faço o comparativo se mudou ou não em relação ao último servidor.

Comment: Na variável $servidores, ele trás TODOS os elementos direito, Agora na hora de jogar o objeto dentro desses arrays ele não coloca os (9,19,29,39...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pagina = 0;
$departament_do_servidor_anterior = null;
$servidores_paginados = [];
foreach ($servidores as $index => $servidor) {
    if ($index > 0 && $departament_do_servidor_anterior !== $servidor->cd_departamento) {
        $pagina++;
    }

    $servidores_paginados[$pagina][] = $servidor;
    $departament_do_servidor_anterior = $servidor->cd_departamento;

    if (count($servidores_paginados[$pagina]) === 9) {
        $pagina++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda @Adir Kuhn.

Answer (score 0):

Douglas, eu atualizei o código que você postou com mais legibilidade para ficar fácil de identificar o erro.

```
$depByPage = '';

foreach ($servidores as $value => $servidor) {

    $servidor->ferias = $ferias[$value]->ferias;
    $dep = $servidor->cd_departamento;

    if($value === 0){
        $pdep = $dep;
        $depByPage = $dep;
    }

    /* Criar mais um array de elementos caso atinja o limite de servidores
     * por página ou se o departamento é diferente
     */
    if ($j >= 9 || $dep != $depByPage) {
        $j = 0;
        $p++;
        $depByPage = $dep;

        $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;
        continue; //Vai diretamente para o inicio do loop
    }      

    $serv[$p][$j] = $servidor;

    $j++;
}
```

Atualize o seu código e veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: infelizmente continua. Ele está "Comendo" os elementos 10,20,30,40 e assim por diante.

Comment: A variável `$pdep` seria o departamento específico para cada página?

Comment: Essa variável ela serve para guardar o departamento do 1º servidor. Ela é usada em outra parte do código que não interfere essa parte.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @douglaspjuizfora, tenta agora!